# How to randomize numbers with no repeat in C?

Tags: c

I want to randomize number in each element of array in a variabel. I currently use `srand()` function. But, with this function i could get a same number in two or more element of array.

the output of my program is
        number[0]=6
        number[1]=3
        number[2]=8
        number[3]=3

See, `number[1]` and `number[3]` has same value. How to prevent this thing happen?

Comment: You can imitate  a poor man's implementation of set by iterating through the array to find out whether the next number is in the array or not before adding it to the array.

Comment: Also, your probably use rand() and not srand() to generate the random elements.

Comment: Well that's the thing with randomness, you can get two results that are the same, you can even get *all* results being the same.

Comment: You mean [Dilbertian Randomness](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25)?